# using monotouch in game engines

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, unity-game-engine, unreal-development-kit

as you know monotouch is the c# face of ios native api. is there any opportunity to use monotouch in ios games? i examined unity3d and unreal development kit. there is no ephesized feature like this. is there any way to use c# in an ios game engine?

For example: i want to start a phone call in a game

Comment: This question made sense until you stated you want to make a phone call in a game. You can do that from anywhere in an app just by opening a `tel:` URL...

Comment: Have you taken a look at xnatouch? http://monogame.codeplex.com/  It's an attempt to combine Microsoft's XNA Framework, and MonoTouch. I don't know how mature it is though.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity iPhone you can access native features of iOS by calling them through plugins.  Usually those plugin methods are written in ObjC/C/C++.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

It might be possible to write plugins using MonoTouch, and access them from Unity after they've been compiled to native code, but I seriously doubt anyone has attempted that.

Comment: i think there is no product Unity iPhone now. instead of it, there is ios products. https://store.unity3d.com/shop/ for developing plugin you must have pro version that means $3000. also there is no trial for ios versions. to try it paying $3000 is too high.even if it works, this price is too high to use c# for native api.

Comment: @atmuc Sorry, Unity iOS used to be called Unity iPhone. Unity iOS doesn't require Pro to use plugins (notice the page say Pro/Mobile-only), so the base cost would be $400. If you contact Unity sales you can get an evaluation version of Unity iOS.  MonoTouch isn't free either. Its base cost is also $400.

Comment: Also, are you aware that Unity's game scripts can be written in Mono C#, and are AOT compiled for iOS, just like MonoTouch?

Comment: http://unity3d.com/support/resources/example-projects/texture-plugins this link says "Plugins are a Unity Pro-only feature"

Comment: @atmuc That example file predates Unity iOS. Why would you trust the wording on a download page over recently updated documentation?

Comment: this is from your link(recently update document) "Note: Plugins are a Pro-only feature. For desktop builds, plugins will work in standalones only. They are disabled when building a Web Player for security reasons". i am waiting response from unity about unity ios trial.it will be the best to have a trial and see that works :-)